# asynchronous GET request method receives data but return null array, works fine while debugging

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, okhttp

**MainActivity.java**

```
String[] captcha = new String[2];

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getMessle();
        }
    });

private void getMessle() {
    captcha[0] = "before";
    captcha[1] = "before2";

    RequestClass rc = new RequestClass();
    captcha = rc.getCaptcha();
    tv.setText(captcha[1]);

}
```

**RequestClass.java**

```
String[] saResult = new String[2];

public String[] getCaptcha() {

    httpUrl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme(strScheme)
            .host(strHost)
            .addPathSegments(path)
            .build();

    request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(httpUrl)
            .addHeader(header, key)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            saResult[0] = response.header("Set-Cookie");
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                saResult[1] = jsonObject.getString("image_url");
            } catch (JSONException je) {

            }
        }
    });
    return saResult;
}
```

I've checked and it doesn't seem like any exceptions are caught. I also know that my application gets a response as well and the datas are definitely there in onResponse(). After some extended testing, it looks like my array is assigned before the response arrives.

Comment: post your json response too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> captcha = rc.getCaptcha();

You call that right after you enqued a request. The request is not executed then nor is there a result. All goes asynchronous.

Only in onResponse() you will get the result. A long time later. And it is in onResponse() that you should handle the result by displaying it in a text view for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My `RequestClass.java` contains all my methods to get/post/put my data and I planned on using it to fetch informations and then handle the display in my different activities, is it still possible or should I transfer my method to the activity classes?

Comment: You could use a callback function or interface to transfer data from onResponse() to the calling activity.

Comment: Knowing my methods return different types (String, String[], and `Object` ) how should I manage this? I haven't used callbacks and interfaces for async very often.

Comment: Well investigate and try.